# White space between Footer and Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got two problems with my website:

**1. unwanted white space between Jumbotron and Footer:**

I tried various solutions posted here and there including stackoverflow however I didn't managed to fix my issue. I have no idea what would cause it.

**2. Columns in the footer are slightly shifted**

Code looks correct, even tho my columns in the footer seem to be floating slightly on the left side

Code can be found here:

**codepen.io/foeva/pen/dMqxyK?editors=1100**

Answer (score 1):

Jumbotron has a standard bottom margin of 30px;

Adding the following to the .jumbotron selector in your css should fix it:

```
margin-bottom: 0;
```

I don't see what's wrong with the columns, they are all equal width and are centered.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, I've tried your solution and unfortunately it didn't bring anticipated results, white space is still there

Comment: Actually, just solved it! I've added 'px' bit after 0 and it worked! Thanks for your help!